# how testing associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec2

please help solve the problem. i have associated models:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum:  50, minimum: 3 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum:  600, minimum: 10 }

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :images
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status
  has_many :albums, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true

  has_attached_file   :avatar, 
                      :styles => { 
                                    :large => "300x300>", 
                                    :medium => "100x100>", 
                                    :thumb => "30x30>" 
                      }, 
                      :default_url => "no_user_ava_3.png"

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
  validates_attachment_file_name :avatar, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/, /gif\Z/]  
end
```

I'm trying to write a test for the model. im create follow factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :status do
    sequence(:id){ |id| id }
    title 'user'
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name){ |i| "us#{i}" }
    sequence(:email){ |i| "us#{i}@ad.ad" }
    password 'qwerty'
    password_confirmation{ |u| u.password } 
    association :status 
  end 
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :album do
    sequence(:title){ |i| "title#{i}" }
    association :user 
    closed nil
    description 'The behavior of or the parent object.'
  end
end
```

my model test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Album do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    Factory.create(:album).should be_valid
  end
end
```

after I run the test, I get the following:

> kalinin@kalinin ~/rails/phs $ rspec spec/models --format documentation
>
> Album   has a valid factory (FAILED - 1)
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) Album has a valid factory
>        Failure/Error: Factory.create(:album).should be_valid
>        NameError:
>          uninitialized constant Factory
>        # ./spec/models/album_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.96458 seconds (files took 2.34 seconds to load) 1
>   example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/models/album_spec.rb:4 # Album has a valid factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:album).should be_valid
```

...instead of:

```
Factory.create(:album).should be_valid
```